# Hexadecimal to decimal converter in C (htoi.c)

Tags: c

Is there any way I can make this code more efficient? I'm new to C, *any* suggestion is welcome!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LIMIT 1024

unsigned long htoi(char s[], int len);

int main(void){
    char line[LIMIT+1];

    int i=0;
    for(int c=0; i<LIMIT-1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i){
        line[i] = c;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';

    printf("%lu\n", htoi(line, i));
}

unsigned long htoi(char s[], int len){

    unsigned long total = 0;
    unsigned short currdigit = 0;
    int power = 0;

    for(int i=len; i>-1; --i){

        if(s[i] == 'X' || s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 0){
            continue;
        }

        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'){ // if it is a numerical char
            currdigit = s[i]-'0';
        }
        else{
            if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'){ // if it's a lower case char
                currdigit = s[i] - 'a';
            }
            else{ // if not, then we assume it is an upper case char (should I?)
                currdigit = s[i] - 'A';
            }

            currdigit+=10;
        }

        total += (currdigit * pow(16, power));

        ++power;
    }

    return total;
}
```

I have a few questions as well:

1. The book I am using to learn C didn't reach the point of teaching pointers yet; however, I do know at least the basics. Is there any way pointers could be used in this program?
2. Should I make change the parameter `char s[]` to `const char s[]` since I am not changing any of its elements' values? Is that common practice?
3. Should I use `short` instead of `int` when I know the number won't surpass great quantities? As an instance, when developing a game, if I know my player's health is from 0 to 100, should I be using a `short` to store that value? And should it be `unsigned` as well if I know it won't be negative?

Answer (score 3):

`#define LIMIT 1024`: magic constants should be named well. What is the limit for? You are also storing the result in an `unsigned long` and contain much less than 1021 hex digits (the last 3 are for `0x` and the null terminator).

Operators should be spaced for better readability: `int i = 0;` and `for (int`

I'm a bit rusty with C, but I think `fgets` can be used instead of rolling your own `getc` loop

Inside `htoi`, a single `tolower` or `toupper` removes the need to check lowercase and capitals

`if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')`: hex digits only contain `0-9` and `a-f` (not `a-z`)

`pow(16, power)`: in this case, `pow(16, power) = 1 << (4 * power)` (see bitshifts). I would split the `4 * power` so that it is more clear what it represents (digit position)

Some changes to the algorithm are necessary: input of `1z00x000` gives `53477376` and `kibe` gives `86718`. I would check if there is a leading `0x` and if there is, to skip it (if not, return an error code)

`if not, then we assume it is an upper case char` and `And should it be unsigned as well if I know it won't be negative`: with your code, I can get `currdigit` to underflow by choosing (for example) a plus sign as input.

Comment: `gets()` should not be used. Lookup "c gets function dangerous", e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/1187415.

Comment: `1 << (4 * power)` is a problem with forming an `unsigned long`.  Recommend `1UL << (4 * power)`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i'm still learning bitwise operators and I hope I'll be proficient enough to use them in my code; is it always best to use bitwise operators when you can? (as in, performance-wise).

Comment: @kibe Bitwise operators should be used when they make the code's intention clear. The performance difference of code using bitwise operators and non-bitwise operators on modern compilers and computers barely make a difference (with very few exceptions). I would suggest reading discussions on performance vs readability [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43151/should-you-sacrifice-code-readability-with-how-efficient-code-is), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183201/should-a-developer-aim-for-readability-or-performance-first).

Comment: @kibe Please consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@FromTheStackAndBack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240776/29485) good answer:

---

> Is there any way I can make this code more efficient?

**Wrong tool for the job, bug**

`pow(16, power)` can be a fairly time expensive to call a floating point function for an integer problem.  Weak implementations may not provide the exact value sought, perhaps just under the expected integer and lead to the wrong answer with integer truncation. Best to stay with integer math.

`currdigit * pow(16, power)` will lead to loss of precision when `long` is 64 bit  and `double` with only 53. --> Wrong result.

Rather than range tests, research `is...()` functions.

**Simplify**

Suggest building the value from `s[0]` to the end.

```
// Algorithm
sum = 0;
while (not done) {
  sum = sum*16 + char_to_digit(char)
  next char
}
```

> Is there any way pointers could be used in this program?

Yes - see below.  Note that `s` of `char s[]` is a pointer.

> Should I make change the parameter `char s[]` to `const char s[]` since I am not changing any of its elements' values? Is that common practice?

Yes, you should - it is common.   It also allows code to call with a `const char[]`.

> Should I use `short` instead of `int` when I know the number won't surpass great quantities?

No. `int` is the size the processor is typically best at both in speed and code footprint.  Use `short` when you have an array or many instances of that type.

If pressed, could use `int16fast_t` and perhaps reap some benefit.  Yet this is a micro-optimization for 1 or 2 variables.

> As an instance, when developing a game, if I know my player's health is from 0 to 100, should I be using a `short` to store that value?

Yes, or even `unsigned char` if you have lots of players.  Else no.  For one player - do not concern about this.  Code for clarity.

> should it be `unsigned` as well if I know it won't be negative?

IMO yes, but you will find various opinions on this one.

---

Other observations

**Leading X**

`if(s[i] == 'X' || s[i] == 'x'...)` allows for an X anywhere in the `char[]`.  Usually an X is only allowed as a leading character or as 0x.

**No detection of non-hex characters**

**No detection of overflow**

**No allowance for a sign character**

**String**

`unsigned long htoi(char s[], int len)` operation on a `char` array without needing a terminating *null character* as in a *string*.  This may be the goal, yet more C-like to expect a final *null character* and drop the need for `len`.

---

Sample alternative.  TBD: how to handle errors?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

unsigned long htoi(const char *s) {
  unsigned long value = 0;
  bool digit_found = false;

  // Allow leading spaces?  This is common
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *s)) {
    s++;
  }

  // Perhaps allow for a sign?
  int sign = *s;
  if (*s == '-' || *s == '+') {
    s++;
  }

  // Detect X, 0X prefix - adjust to needs
  if (*s == 'X' || *s == 'x') {
    s++; // consume it
  } else if (*s == '0' && (s[1] == 'X' || s[1] == 'x') && 
      isxdigit((unsigned char) *s[2])) {
    s += 2;
  }

  while (isxdigit((unsigned char ) *s)) {
    int digit;
    if (isdigit((unsigned char) *s)) digit = *s - '0';
    else digit = toupper((unsigned char) *s) - 'A' + 10;

    if (value >= ULONG_MAX / 16) {
      // we have overflow - various ways to handle. Here code just limits
      value = ULONG_MAX;
    } else {
      value = value * 16 + (unsigned) digit;
    }
    digit_found = true;
    s++;
  }

  if (!digit_found) {
    // Error, nothing to convert, ignore for now
  }

  // Allow trailing spaces?  This is not common, but I like it.
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *s)) {
    s++;
  }

  if (*s) {
    // Error, trailing non-numeric text, ignore for now
  }

  if (sign == '-') {
    // TBD is this OK, sure -0 is OK, but should -123 wrap or what?
    // For now, just make 0
    value = 0;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: kibe, Minor: with `char line[LIMIT+1]; ... i<LIMIT-1`, use `i < LIMIT` or `i < sizeof line - 1`.

Comment: chux, thank you so much for taking your time to better my code, seriously! I understood every bit of your example; however, why is it needed to cast `unsigned char` every time you check if it is a digit? (and when calling `toupper` as well). either way, thank you so much!

Comment: @kibe Only a concern when `x < 0`.  `is...(int x)` functions are defined for `int` values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  When `char ch` is _signed_ and `ch < 0`, `is...(ch)` is UB.  When processing _characters_, code should use values in the 0-255 range.  Same for `to...()`.